# Wrapping text labels

Tags: d3.js

Currently trying to wrap some text labels on my graph. I'm following Mike Bostock's example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321). When I tried implementing his example it works for my y-axis but I need it to work on my x-axis and I'm not exactly sure why it's not working.

```
 chart2.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Potential Years Lost")
        .call(wrap, x0.rangeBand());


  function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/flyingburrito/0xq0qc42/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small change, you weren't actually calling `wrap` on the x-axis tick text (you were only calling it for the y-axis label).

You needed to add the final two lines to this block where the x-axis is appended

```
//draw the bars
chart2.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
    .call(wrap, x0.rangeBand());
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/v5fj0263/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Foreign Object with html :

1. Add Foreign Object then use xhtml content.

```js
var fo = nodes.append("foreignObject")
  .style("pointer-events", "none")
  .attr("id", "fo")
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return Math.max(32, this.getComputedTextLength() + 12);
  });

fo.append("xhtml:body")
  .style("text-align", "center")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "fotext")
  .style("margin", "0px auto")
  .style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
  .style("overflow", "auto")
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.name
  });

fo.attr("transform", function(d) {
  return translateInMiddle(this)
});

function translateInMiddle(object) {
  bbox = object.getBBox();
  return "translate(" + [-bbox.width / 2, -bbox.height / 8] + ")";
}
```