# D3.js Decision Tree - text wraping, bounding box, # of load circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, interactive, flowchart

I'm trying to create a decision tree in D3.

Problems:
- The text goes off the right side, can/how do I set a bounding box to stop that?

- The text in the circle isn't wrapping. I am willing to make circles bigger to fit the text, but the wrapping is still a problem.
- How do I get only the first 3 circles to show on load?

```js
var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "TK question here that's long",
    "content":"Question here long",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level"
      }
    ]
  }
];


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 width = 860 - margin.right - margin.left,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var i = 0,
 duration = 750,
 root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
 .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
  
update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
   links = tree.links(nodes);
    
    

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
    
    

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
   .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
   .attr("r", 1e-6)
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
    


  nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -33 : 13; })
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
    
      nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.content; });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
   .attr("r", 30)
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
   .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
   .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   })
   .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
 d.x0 = d.x;
 d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
 d._children = d.children;
 d.children = null;
  } else {
 d.children = d._children;
 d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

```css
 .node {
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text {
   font: 12px sans-serif;
 }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Tree Example</title>

  </head>

  <body>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the wrapping of the text mike bostock covered that in this example: [text wrapping in d3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/267208068dbb75285114) and for the showing of only certain nodes, you should include a filter after the data to show only certain tipes of data (i.e. the nodes that have either no parents or one parent and son (so the first and the middle ones)

Comment: I think you meant to link to this : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

I have added the function wrap from that to my code but it doesn't work.

Comment: yes my bad wrong link! the function works, are you sure you're providing the right values and calling it after the text is created?

Comment: I just need to change "value" at the bottom of the function to "content" right? I guess not, I can't seem to make it work... http://jsfiddle.net/jarstin07/g8x4gpkt/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g8x4gpkt/1/ on line 103 is where the wrap function is used. Still needs a bit of tweaking by your side but at least it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

you can check this post.. [Wrapping text labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694444/wrapping-text-labels/29784575#29784575) also in the foreignObject you can add x and y based on radius of the circle.

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append(\"g\")
      .attr(\"class\", \"node\")
      .attr(\"transform\", function(d) { 
          d.radius = (d.x - 90); // add some data to use in ForeignObject
          return \"translate(\" + source.y0 + \",\" + source.x0 + \")\"; 
      })
      .on(\"click\", click);
```